# Reservation or reservations?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have booked a table for ten at a restaurant. Now, I need to inform them that I have done so.
Do I say,"The reservation**s** are for 11.30." or "The reservation is for 11.30." ?

Alternatively, can I use "The table is booked for 11.30"?

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: How so? When talking about a single reservation, it has to be reservation and not reservations. I understand that "The reservations are for 11.30." is a correct sentence, I just don't think it applies to his example about informing someone about ONE reservation.

Comment: @J_LV Because it could refer to a single reservation for a group of ten people, or a group of reservations made for ten people (i.e., one per person). I've seen both forms used interchangeably: "We have reservations at XXXX" or "We have a reservation at XXXX".

Comment: I had not thought about that. I got hung up on the "a table" (singular) thing. But I guess that doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the actual number of reservations. Thank you!

Comment: In practice they're interchangeable.  If one wants to be retentive about it, then the singular should be used if there is presumably only one entry for one time in the reservation book, but the grammar police won't arrest you if you use the plural.

Comment: Having **reservations** about a restaurant means it is likely you won't go at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a single reservation for ten people all sitting at one table.  The reservation is singular, so you say "The reservation is for 11.30."

Answer (score 2):

You have booked **a** table for ten at a restaurant.

A **single table** qualifies as a **single reservation**, therefore singular verb.

> The table is booked for 11.30 or the table is reserved for 11.30, both are grammatical.

If you have booked say **three separate tables** for ten at a restaurant.

> The tables are booked/reserved for 11.30, would be the appropriate choice.However, they could still be put under one reservation by the restaurant.